# JavaFX. Trying to instantiate a stage inside a controller does not retrieve value inside it?or does it?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, javafx-8

Environment: Java FX 8 using Scene Builder

Context: I was trying to create a simple stage containing a `TableView` and `TableColumn` using `ObservableList`. The `create_ConfigStage()` is called to create stage and well `initialize()` is initialize. the FXML's controller class is `ControllerA`(this very class) and Everything went fine until..

Problem: Cant figure out why the call for `words.size` in `create_ConfigStage()` caused NullPointerException(or 0) but calling the same in `initialize()` yields no problem.

Problem Type : `java.lang.NullPointerException` or to be precise value initialized in `initialized()` is not initialized after stage creation(or something like that).

FYI: No other stuffs are messing with `words` variable or even `templates` variable.

Additional Test:

1. Just added the Button to test the size of word with `button` and `handleButton`. The results are ok again. But still nullpointer in the same old place.
2. Just added a string `testVal` to see if value changes. Apparently, it didn't.

   ```
   class ControllerA {

   @FXML TableView<Words> templatesTable;
   @FXML TableColumn<Words, String> templateHeaders;
   @FXML Button button;

   Stage stage;
   ObservableList<Words> templates;
   List<Words> words = new ArrayList<Words>();
   String testVal = "Nothing Happened";

   @FXML
   public void initialize(){
       words = FileUtil.readMacroFile(new File("macros.dat"));
       templates = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
       templates.addAll(words);
       templatesTable.setItems(templates);
       templateHeaders.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Words, String>("header"));
       testVal = "Something Happened";

       System.out.println(words.size()); //<<-- size = 5 (THIS IS PRINTED)
   }

   public void create_ConfigStage() {
       stage = new Stage();
       FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("windows/configureTemplates.fxml"));
       AnchorPane root = null;

       try {
           root = loader.load();
           Scene scene = new Scene(root);
           stage.setScene(scene);
           stage.showAndWait();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

       System.out.println(testVal); //This one prints "Nothing Happened" instead of "Something happened"!!!
       System.out.println(words.size()); //<<-- The line showing null pointer(if wasnt initialized in initializer() else shows 0)
    }

   @FXML
   public void handleButton(){
       System.out.println(words.size()); // <<-- this one prints 5(THIS IS PRINTED AS WELL)
   }
   ```

The code that invokes the create_ConfigStage()

```
public class Main_Controller {
@FXML Button createConfig;

@FXML
    public void handleConfigTemplateRequest(){
        main.getControllerA().create_ConfigStage();
        //This method is invoked by "createConfig" button
    }
}
```

This is the class that calls creates the primary stage

```
public class Main extends Application{

public void start(Stage mainStage) throws Exception{
    this.primaryStage = mainStage;
    mainStage.setTitle("Scratch GLSL Editor");

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("main.fxml"));   //main.fxml's controller is class Main_Controller
    AnchorPane root = loader.load();

    Scene mainScene = new Scene(root);
    mainStage.setScene(mainScene);
    mainStage.show();

    ControllerA controllerA = new ControllerA();
    controllerA.setMain(this); //to get the controller from this class
    setControllerA(controllerA);

}

//setter and getter for ControllerA here

public static void main(String[] args){
     launch(args);
}
}
```

Comment: When are you invoking create_ConfigStage method? What is the name of the controller class which create_ConfigStage method belongs?

Comment: create_ConfigStage() is inside the controller class where it is located (I located create_ConfigStage in a controller class and then identified it as a controller). And it is called directly by another Stage when a button is pressed, Do you need Code for that too?

Comment: The best way to spot null pointers is to go in debug mode and just track down the culprit.

Comment: I'm sorry but I tried. But this is a wierd Nullpointer I've ever encountered.

Comment: This problem just keeps getting more and more weird.

Comment: Can you show how you are calling `create_ConfigStage()` and how you are getting the reference the the controller instance on which you are calling it? It's not at all clear to me why you would expect `initialize()` to have been called on *this instance* of the controller. Obviously, it will have been called on the instance created by the FXML loader, but that is a completely different instance.

Comment: the `initialize()` method is guaranteed called else I wouldn't have gotten the value 5 in `handleButton()` method.

Comment: But the `handleButton()` method, like the `initialize()` method, is called *on the instance created by the `FXMLLoader`*. Unless you are performing some magic in code you haven't shown us, the `create_ConfigStage()` method is called on a completely different instance. Again, **show the code where you invoke `create_ConfigStage()`** and how you are getting the instance on which you call that method.

Comment: is there a reason why this question got negative points?

Comment: Yes: you keep refusing to show the code you've been asked to show (by two different people). Now at least you have shown where you invoke `create_ConfigStage()` but you still haven't shown where the reference to the controller comes from. There is no reason whatsoever to believe `initialize()` was ever called on that instance of `ControllerA`.

Comment: Fine. let me recreate the entire code.

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), specifically "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the *shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself*." And, if it helps more, http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: if I knew the problem I would have solved it myself. I have given much code trying to reduce "too much code" limit. No disrespect intended but this is getting tedious. (FYI : i never refused to show code. Maybe I misunderstood but never refused)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instance of `ControllerA` on which you invoke `create_ConfigStage()` is created by the line

```
ControllerA controllerA = new ControllerA();
```

In other words, it is not created for you as part of the `load(...)` process of the `FXMLLoader`. Consequently, any `FXML`-injected fields are not initialized, and the `initialize()` method is never called on that instance.

Later, when you load the FXML, the `FXMLLoader` creates *another* instance of `ControllerA`, and as part of the `load(...)` process invokes `initialize()` on *that* instance. When the button is pressed, the event handler method is invoked on that same `FXMLLoader`-created instance.

Consequently, `words` is properly initialized from your `FileUtil.readMacroFile(...)` method in the `FXMLLoader`-created instance, but is never properly initialized in the instance you create yourself. So for the instance on which you invoke `create_ConfigStage()`, `words` is the empty `ArrayList` you create inline in the declaration (or `null` if you omit the `= new ArrayList<Words>()` from the declaration).

It's not abundantly clear what you are trying to do, as you haven't really shown the relationship between your FXML files and the various controllers, but to get the instance of the controller that was loaded by an `FXMLLoader` you would use code like

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("windows/configureTemplates.fxml"));

AnchorPane root = null;

try {
    root = loader.load();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.showAndWait();
    ControllerA controllerA = loader.getController();
    System.out.println(controllerA.getWords().size());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

with a suitable `getWords()` method defined in `ControllerA`:

```
public List<Words> getWords() {
    return words ;
}
```

Obviously you couldn't do this in an instance method of `ControllerA`, since you create a chicken-and-egg situation (you need to get the controller instance from the `FXMLLoader`, but you don't invoke the `FXMLLoader` until you have the controller instance).

The reason you are running into problems here is that you are trying to invert the usual FXML loading process. The usual process works like this:

1. Create an `FXMLLoader`
2. Call `load(...)` on the `FXMLLoader`
3. The `FXMLLoader` reads the FXML file
4. The `FXMLLoader` creates the controller, as specified by the `fx:controller` attribute in the FXML file

In other words, the FXML file (the *view*) instantiates the controller for you.

You are trying to do things the other way around, i.e. you are trying to have your controller instance create the `FXMLLoader` and subsequently load the view. You can make things work this way, but you have to set it up differently. The following assumes you are not loading this FXML file anywhere else (you would at a minimum have to modify that code accordingly).

First, **remove the `fx:controller` attribute from `configureTemplates.fxml`** (since you are going to create the controller before you create the `FXMLLoader`, you don't want the loader instantiating the controller class any more).

Then modify your `create_ConfigStage()` method as follows:

```
public void create_ConfigStage() {
    stage = new Stage();
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("windows/configureTemplates.fxml"));

    // Tell the FXMLLoader to use this object as the controller.
    // Note that if the fxml file has a fx:controller attribute, 
    // loading it will fail with an IllegalStateException:

    loader.setController(this);


    AnchorPane root = null;

    try {
        // Since we set this object as the controller, loading will 
        // initialize all the @FXML fields defined in this instance, and will
        // invoke initialize() on this instance:
        root = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.showAndWait();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(testVal); // This should show the value updated in initialize()
    System.out.println(words.size()); // This should give the number loaded by FileUtil.readMacroFile(...)
}
```

You might also want to read up on [this related technique](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#custom_components).

Answer (score 0):

I think this line makes word to be null:

```
 words = FileUtil.readMacroFile()
```

So you need to check that method in FileUtil to see when it returns null.

Comment: No, there is a statement `System.out.println(words.size()); //<<-- size = 5` which shows that it does not make it null.

Comment: Then something isn't right. This can't be. Can you put stacktrace?

Comment: its really long(100 lines). are you sure?

Comment: At least the top 10 - 15 lines.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem while trying to build advanced dialogs which contents were defined through FXML files.

What worked for me was:

- defining the dialog content as a FXML file, including the declaration of its controller
- in the controller, define the dialog as a private static member, loaded from an utility class (the static keyword makes it instanciated before the controller itself is fully built)
- build the controller as a singleton, the instance is initialized in the initialize() method called when the Controller is built by the FXML loader

Be careful not to use the dialog in the initialize() method as it isn't ready yet, I spent some time to figure why and James_D's answer helped me a lot!

The FXML definition of the dialog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane id="popup" fx:id="mainPane"
        xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8"
        xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
        fx:controller="org.example.controllers.MyDialogController"/>
```

The dialog's controller class:

```
public class MyDialogController implements Initializable {
    private static ObservationTactileDialogController instance;

    // FxmlDialog.java is a custom class extending Dialog<>
    // and provides a loader
    private static FxmlDialog<LinkedList<ObservationDTO>> dialog =
        new FxmlDialog<>("/fxml/dialog.fxml");

    private ResultType result;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        instance = this;
        // do your own stuff here...
    }

    public ResultType edit() {
        dialog.getDialogStage().showAndWait();

        return result;
    }

    public MyDialogController getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    // some business logic to built the result
}
```

Then in any other controller method you can use this dialog like this:

```
MyDialogController dialogController = MyDialogController.getInstance();
ResultType result = dialogController.edit();
```

I hope this helps!